# GWT and Jetty - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: gwt, jetty

I'm starting a servlet extending google's RemoteServiceServlet in Jetty. It did not work with this error:
HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

I searched this error and found that RemoteServiceServlet does not implement doGet and doPost. 
I tried this link http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/GWT. It didn't work either.
Any ideas how I can get it to work?
Should I send back the html file in the doGet?What should I do in the doPost?

Thank you

Comment: Any chance for the code of the servlet? :]

Answer (score 2):

RemoteServiceServlet is designed to be used with [GWTRPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideCreatingServices). This means, that you don't implement `doPost` or `doGet` at all (doPost is even final in `AbstractRemoteServiceServlet`). You implement your own service methods instead, which you specify in your `RemoteService` interface.

If you want to implement doPost/doGet yourself, *instead of* using GWTRPC (see ["Making HTTP Requests"](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests) in the GWT documentation), then extend the usual `HttpServlet` instead of `RemoteServiceServlet`. If you need both, I would suggest to create two separate servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `super.doGet(req, resp)` in my doGet method helped me. Anyway there is not much usefull operations in it.